# Graph the function $g(x) = 3f(({x\over2}) − 1) − 3$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I am looking at the problem set from MIT 18.01 (single variable calculus), in the first problem set I am stuck on this function.

The solution to this function is given as:

The graph is made up of segments joining (0, −6) to (4, 3) to (8, −6). It repeats in a zigzag with period 8. This can be derived using:

(1) ${x\over2} − 1 = −1 =⇒ x = 0$ and $g(0) = 3f(−1) − 3 = −6$

(2) ${x\over2} − 1 = 1 =⇒ x = 4$ and $g(4) = 3f(1) − 3 = 3$

(3) ${x\over2} − 1 = 3 =⇒ x = 8$ and $g(8) = 3f(3) − 3 = −6$

I have understood how the value of x has been derived but can't figure out the respective values at g(0), g(4), g(8).

Could someone tell me how the g(x) or y values have been calculated?

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Comment: F, according to an earlier part of this question, is a piecewise linear function, consists of straight line segments joining the points:
(-1,-1), (1,2), (3,-1) and (5,2).

Comment: You can immediately solve equations 1, 2 and 3 for the values of $f(-1),f(1)$ and $f(3)$.

Comment: I only could understand how the value of x was found, the value for g(x) where x={0,4,8} has been eluding me, i know the solution is simple, but i am having a hard time seeing it for the g(x) part of the function

Comment: When you say "The graph is made up of segments joining . . ." do you  mean the graph of $g$? If that is the case then one could guess that you want to find the graph of $f$ (since you do not say what you want to find). Do you want to find the graph of $f$? The equation of $f$? What exactly do you want to find?

Comment: Ok i finally understood the question, and i figured out the answer. I took your comment regarding solving equations 1,2,3 with the values at f(-1), f(1), f(3). Thanks for your help